# How can I make a procedural polished granite material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, procedural

I have made a polished granite material with a node setup. Using this photograph as reference, how can I improve this further?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Naresh, I think you'll find some resistance to this kind of question because of the subjective nature of perception. That aside, if you want to make it easy for people to offer answers based on your material why not also [include the .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), that way people who do have time don't need recreate the node tree from scratch using the screenshot.

Comment: Although not hugely obvious from the reference image, from my own experience of polished granite it often has flecks of high reflectivity across the surface, stemming from small crystals such as quartz from the rocks formation process. You could perhaps achieve this with a voronoi texture affecting a glossy value below the clear gloss coat above? :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Creating a Procedural Polished Granite Material

---

Guessing you're probably no longer in need of this effect, but thought I'd write a (hopefully) short tutorial in case anyone is interested in creating a **Realistic Procedural Polished Granite Material** in future.

This is the final setup and material that we'll be creating :D

(3mins49secs @ 750x1000px on CPU)
[image: Final Image]
[image: Final Nodes]

---

**1.** We'll start off this material by creating the procedural mottled texture that is present in granite stone (and in your reference image).

Firstly, let's create the lighter sections, using this node setup:

[image: Light Brown]

The nodes are fairly self explanatory, but we're essentially creating and distorting a noise texture using the slot attached to the `Mapping` node. We're then using the `Color Ramp` node to bump up the contrast by just the right amount. Underneath this we are mixing together some colour sampled from the reference using a `Mix RGB` controlled by another `Noise Texture` plugged into the `Fac` input. Finally we'll plug this into the first `Color` input of another `Mix RGB` node with the blending mode set to `Screen` and the bottom value set to white to give us our desired result... *phew*!

Next up is essentially repeating the last step a couple more times to get the darker shades of the granite, as well as the yellow (?!) ones.

As the nodes are pretty much exactly the same with just a few values changed, we can go ahead and simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate them, and move them below.

[image: Dark Colour]
[image: Yellow Colour]

Again fairly self explanatory... but briefly, we'll use the `Mapping` node to essentially create a seed value for the noise, using the Location value to adjust this. The Noise Textures themselves are used to adjust the size of the noise, etc and once again the colours are sampled from the reference images.

The final part of this step is mixing these 3 outputs together. We'll do this by adding 2 more `Mix RGB` nodes with a `Multiply` blend mode, and connecting them accordingly. Don't worry about the white background, that will be cut out at the start of the next step :)

[image: Final Mottles]

---

**2.** In this step we'll be finalising the granite base material. I won't go into details on every little section, but I'll explain the overall concepts.

[image: Final Granite Material Nodes]

So the extra `Mix RGB > Multiply` node is (as promised!) used to cut out that white and add in the creamy brown background colour. This colour is be plugged into a `Diffuse BSDF` shader, which is mixed with a `Glossy BSDF` shader using a `Mix` shader.

Next the crystal fleck mask is created. This is a simply case of using a scaled up `Voronoi Texture` thrown through a `Color Ramp` node plugged into the `Fac` input of the `Mix` shader. A simple step but it helps add another dimension of realism to the material :)

Finally, a procedural bump map is added to the `Normal` input of the diffuse and glossy shaders.

---

**3.** In this third and final step we'll be adding the final clear-coat (polish) effect to the granite material. Its fairly simple, but is slightly more involved than just mixing a glossy shader in... :)

[image: Clear Coat]

The Voronoi setup is used to break up the reflections of the `Glossy BSDF` shader, adding a little bit of roughness here and there. The Noise bump Texture is used to add another level of surface texture. It's a (very... :P) subtle effect, but one that helps give the polish a slightly more 'painted' look.

Finally, we can add this coat over the Granite material, using another `Mix` shader controlled by a `Layer Weight` node. You can use a `Fresnel` node or other inputs to control this, but I used the `Facing` output because it looked pretty nice! ;)

[image: Adding the Coat]

---

So there we go! A sweet, **fully procedural** Polished Granite Material setup! :D

[image: Final Setup and Render]

Hope it helps and don't forget to **upvote/mark as the right answer** if you liked it! :)

Comment: As an extra point, I also put together a tutorial on adding non-procedural realism to materials which might complement this material nicely... :) http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32494/how-to-make-dirty-looking-object/33054#33054

Comment: 2 years later and this still helps people! Great answer! Helped me creating this material: https://imgur.com/a/ncfYyoQ

Comment: Hey thanks, @S.Visser , glad people are still finding it helpful!