# How can I individually scale the voronoi color chunks?

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

I'm trying to make sort of a granite slab material for flooring. And i've tried a lot of things, but none seem to make it look good, and using the image doesn't help either since there's changes in brightness.
My main idea was to use a voronoi texture as a base from where to build up. I get sort of close, but not really there.
It doesn't seem that hard in theory, but making all the layers from big chunks to small details makes it all the more difficult.
Could anyone tell me a way to start off? Maybe not even procedurally

Edit: I'll just ask a simple question where I can go on from, **how can I decrease the size of the chunks individually in the voronoi color socket?**

[image: The material in question]

Comment: and  [How can I make a procedural polished granite material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40920/how-can-i-make-a-procedural-polished-granite-material)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely on the right track with the Voronoi textures - Just use 3 ones of different scale to get that random sized pebble effect. Clamp off some of the values with ColorRamps, so it's not too noisy, and when you multiply them together, use one as a mix factor (each time - hard to see on my second multiply node but its there) to reduce the influence of the overlaps.

[image: Voronoi1]

The last step is to add a simple noise texture to give some color variance to the background:

[image: Voroni2]