# add scratches to metal material

Tags: texturing

I'm working on a short with a CGI robot. I found this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUmamyB-C6o

I'm trying to achieve a similar look with the scratches. The node setup he has in the video, looks quiet complex and I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Is the best approach to add metal scratches is to create a UV map, that I can add to the metal, sort of like what I did on the face? Is there a different approach?

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific. Vague, broad and open ended terms like "advice" "ideas" "better" or "more realistic" are hard to pin down, and answers are going to be opinion based, not really suited for the format of this site. You might want to try posting on a forum like blenderartists.org or re-format your question to address a specific issue you want to resolve.

Comment: Done. I added a more specific question, regarding achieving a realistic metal scratch look. I don't want to apply all over the body of the robot, but in specific areas. And I'm trying to figure out the best approach to do that.

Comment: this has been asked before, see if any of this helps http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=metal+scratches

Comment: See also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32494/how-to-make-dirty-looking-object/33054#33054 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21283/add-scratches-to-a-material-in-cycles

Comment: Great, thanks for all the pointers. Will take a detailed look at these examples.